# setFieldWeights doesn't work

Tags: php, search, sphinx

I'm using sphinx php api to sort  search results. I want to give more weight to title and less to content, I've tried setting setFieldWeights
`$sp->setFieldWeights(array('title'=>10,'full_story'=>1));` but it's not working at all. not matter how i change the weight, results stays the same.

print_r with "test" as a search word and `setFieldWeights(array('title'=>10,'full_story'=>1));`

```
Array ( [error] => [warning] => [status] => 0 [fields] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => full_story [2] => category ) [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2 ) [matches] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1933 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2824 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2860 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 2865 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5720 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6963 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 8190 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 8591 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 10114 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 10157 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 11162 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 11659 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 13219 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 13220 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 13565 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 13576 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 14801 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 14857 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 17311 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [19] => Array ( [id] => 17511 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [20] => Array ( [id] => 18131 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 19171 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [22] => Array ( [id] => 21134 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [23] => Array ( [id] => 23007 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [24] => Array ( [id] => 23230 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [25] => Array ( [id] => 23460 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [26] => Array ( [id] => 23473 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [27] => Array ( [id] => 25609 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [28] => Array ( [id] => 28093 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [29] => Array ( [id] => 28175 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [30] => Array ( [id] => 30364 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [31] => Array ( [id] => 30506 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [32] => Array ( [id] => 31439 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [33] => Array ( [id] => 31668 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [34] => Array ( [id] => 32017 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [35] => Array ( [id] => 1432 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [36] => Array ( [id] => 5362 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [37] => Array ( [id] => 9175 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [38] => Array ( [id] => 13817 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [39] => Array ( [id] => 14132 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [40] => Array ( [id] => 14658 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [41] => Array ( [id] => 15792 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [42] => Array ( [id] => 16615 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [43] => Array ( [id] => 18177 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [44] => Array ( [id] => 18581 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [45] => Array ( [id] => 18618 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [46] => Array ( [id] => 18665 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [47] => Array ( [id] => 18718 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [48] => Array ( [id] => 19096 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [49] => Array ( [id] => 19128 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [50] => Array ( [id] => 19464 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [51] => Array ( [id] => 20014 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [52] => Array ( [id] => 20144 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [53] => Array ( [id] => 20306 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 ) ) [54] => Array ( [id] => 22604 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [55] => Array ( [id] => 23870 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [56] => Array ( [id] => 23994 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [57] => Array ( [id] => 24507 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [58] => Array ( [id] => 24617 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [59] => Array ( [id] => 25043 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [60] => Array ( [id] => 25350 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [61] => Array ( [id] => 26063 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [62] => Array ( [id] => 26614 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [63] => Array ( [id] => 26819 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [64] => Array ( [id] => 28292 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [65] => Array ( [id] => 29155 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [66] => Array ( [id] => 30854 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [67] => Array ( [id] => 31566 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [68] => Array ( [id] => 31704 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) [69] => Array ( [id] => 32092 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 ) ) ) [total] => 70 [total_found] => 70 [time] => 0,017 [words] => Array ( [*test*] => Array ( [docs] => 70 [hits] => 70 ) ) )
```

print_r with "test" as a search word and `setFieldWeights(array('title'=>10000,'full_story'=>1));`

```
Array ( [error] => [warning] => [status] => 0 [fields] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => full_story [2] => category [3] => date ) [attrs] => Array ( ) [matches] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1933 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2824 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2860 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 2865 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5720 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6963 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 8190 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 8591 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 10114 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 10157 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 11162 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 11659 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 13219 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 13220 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 13565 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 13576 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 14801 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 14857 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 17311 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [19] => Array ( [id] => 17511 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [20] => Array ( [id] => 18131 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 19171 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [22] => Array ( [id] => 21134 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [23] => Array ( [id] => 23007 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [24] => Array ( [id] => 23230 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [25] => Array ( [id] => 23460 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [26] => Array ( [id] => 23473 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [27] => Array ( [id] => 25609 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [28] => Array ( [id] => 28093 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [29] => Array ( [id] => 28175 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [30] => Array ( [id] => 30364 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [31] => Array ( [id] => 30506 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [32] => Array ( [id] => 31439 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [33] => Array ( [id] => 31668 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [34] => Array ( [id] => 32017 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [35] => Array ( [id] => 1432 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [36] => Array ( [id] => 5362 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [37] => Array ( [id] => 9175 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [38] => Array ( [id] => 13817 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [39] => Array ( [id] => 14132 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [40] => Array ( [id] => 14658 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [41] => Array ( [id] => 15792 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [42] => Array ( [id] => 16615 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [43] => Array ( [id] => 18177 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [44] => Array ( [id] => 18581 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [45] => Array ( [id] => 18618 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [46] => Array ( [id] => 18665 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [47] => Array ( [id] => 18718 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [48] => Array ( [id] => 19096 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [49] => Array ( [id] => 19128 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [50] => Array ( [id] => 19464 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [51] => Array ( [id] => 20014 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [52] => Array ( [id] => 20144 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [53] => Array ( [id] => 20306 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [54] => Array ( [id] => 22604 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [55] => Array ( [id] => 23870 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [56] => Array ( [id] => 23994 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [57] => Array ( [id] => 24507 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [58] => Array ( [id] => 24617 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [59] => Array ( [id] => 25043 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [60] => Array ( [id] => 25350 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [61] => Array ( [id] => 26063 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [62] => Array ( [id] => 26614 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [63] => Array ( [id] => 26819 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [64] => Array ( [id] => 28292 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [65] => Array ( [id] => 29155 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [66] => Array ( [id] => 30854 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [67] => Array ( [id] => 31566 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [68] => Array ( [id] => 31704 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [69] => Array ( [id] => 32092 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) ) [total] => 70 [total_found] => 70 [time] => 0,000 [words] => Array ( [*test*] => Array ( [docs] => 70 [hits] => 70 ) ) )
```

print_r with "test" as a search word without `setFieldWeights`

```
Array ( [error] => [warning] => [status] => 0 [fields] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => full_story [2] => category [3] => date ) [attrs] => Array ( ) [matches] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1432 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1933 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2824 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 2860 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 2865 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 5362 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 5720 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 6963 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 8190 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 8591 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 9175 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 10114 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 10157 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 11162 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 11659 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 13219 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 13220 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 13565 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 13576 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [19] => Array ( [id] => 13817 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [20] => Array ( [id] => 14132 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 14658 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [22] => Array ( [id] => 14801 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [23] => Array ( [id] => 14857 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [24] => Array ( [id] => 15792 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [25] => Array ( [id] => 16615 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [26] => Array ( [id] => 17311 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [27] => Array ( [id] => 17511 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [28] => Array ( [id] => 18131 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [29] => Array ( [id] => 18177 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [30] => Array ( [id] => 18581 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [31] => Array ( [id] => 18618 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [32] => Array ( [id] => 18665 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [33] => Array ( [id] => 18718 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [34] => Array ( [id] => 19096 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [35] => Array ( [id] => 19128 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [36] => Array ( [id] => 19171 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [37] => Array ( [id] => 19464 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [38] => Array ( [id] => 20014 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [39] => Array ( [id] => 20144 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [40] => Array ( [id] => 20306 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [41] => Array ( [id] => 21134 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [42] => Array ( [id] => 22604 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [43] => Array ( [id] => 23007 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [44] => Array ( [id] => 23230 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [45] => Array ( [id] => 23460 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [46] => Array ( [id] => 23473 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [47] => Array ( [id] => 23870 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [48] => Array ( [id] => 23994 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [49] => Array ( [id] => 24507 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [50] => Array ( [id] => 24617 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [51] => Array ( [id] => 25043 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [52] => Array ( [id] => 25350 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [53] => Array ( [id] => 25609 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [54] => Array ( [id] => 26063 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [55] => Array ( [id] => 26614 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [56] => Array ( [id] => 26819 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [57] => Array ( [id] => 28093 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [58] => Array ( [id] => 28175 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [59] => Array ( [id] => 28292 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [60] => Array ( [id] => 29155 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [61] => Array ( [id] => 30364 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [62] => Array ( [id] => 30506 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [63] => Array ( [id] => 30854 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [64] => Array ( [id] => 31439 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [65] => Array ( [id] => 31566 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [66] => Array ( [id] => 31668 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [67] => Array ( [id] => 31704 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [68] => Array ( [id] => 32017 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) [69] => Array ( [id] => 32092 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( ) ) ) [total] => 70 [total_found] => 70 [time] => 0,000 [words] => Array ( [*test*] => Array ( [docs] => 70 [hits] => 70 ) ) )
```

sphinx php api

```
                        // Include the sphinx API class
                        require(ENGINE_DIR . "/modules/sphinxapi.php");

                        $sp = new SphinxClient();
                        $sp->setFieldWeights(array('title'=>10,'full_story'=>1));
                        $sp->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_all);
                        $sp->SetArrayResult(true);
                        $sp->SetLimits(0,$count_result = ($config['search_number'] * 5));

                        $query = explode(" ",$story);
                        $query = implode(array_map(function($item) { return ' *' . $item . '* '; }, $query));
                        $results = $sp->Query($query, $config['sphinx_index']);

                        print_r($results);

                        $count_result = $results['total_found'];
                        $result_count = $count_result;
```

than i'm performing a select in on ids

```
$sql_request = "SELECT * from post WHERE id IN {$rIds} LIMIT $search_start,{$config['search_number']}";
```

sphinx conf

```
        type                    = mysql
        sql_host                = localhost
        sql_user                = user
        sql_pass                = pass
        sql_db                  = user

        sql_port                = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

        sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM post
        sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
        sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET utf8
        sql_query_pre = SET SESSION query_cache_type=OFF

        sql_query               = SELECT id, title, full_story, category, DATE FROM post WHERE approve='1'     AND id <=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )

        #sql_attr_timestamp     = DATE

        sql_ranged_throttle = 0
```

index

```
index online_test
{
        source                  = online_test_posts
        path                    = /var/lib/sphinx/online_test
        docinfo                 = extern
        charset_type            = utf-8
        morphology              = stem_enru

        min_word_len            = 1
        min_prefix_len          = 0
        min_infix_len           = 1

        mlock = 0

        charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F

        enable_star = 1
        rt_mem_limit = 512M
}
```

my indication is a post with a title "Test Your Brain" with an id '2865' it's should be at least second. instead i'm getting post with a title "Coming & Going" with `full_story` content `test`, id post - `1432`

by the way, if I'm running search from command line the results are much more accurate.

```
search test
index 'online_test': query 'test ': returned 7 matches of 7 total in 0.008 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=2865, weight=1684
2. document=5362, weight=1684
3. document=8190, weight=1684
4. document=23460, weight=1684
5. document=25609, weight=1684
6. document=31704, weight=1684
7. document=32092, weight=1684
```

Comment: You need to supply more details, example queries used, text from documents, and query results with and without the fieldweights. Need to see that the weight of documents should change, from the little information provided so far its not clear it should change.

Comment: @barryhunter edited. is that enough info?

Comment: Well enough to guess its actully your mysql $sql_request that is incorrect, not sphinx :) [see answer below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've proved yourself, that setFieldWeights **is** working :)

When no weights:      `[4] => Array ( [id] => 2865 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( )`

When 10: `[4] => Array ( [id] => 5720 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 )`

When 10000:  `[4] => Array ( [id] => 5720 [weight] => 10000 [attrs] => Array ( )`

And when have weights set, you have documents with different weights:

```
[34] => Array ( [id] => 32017 [weight] => 10 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2013 )
[35] => Array ( [id] => 1432 [weight] => 1 [attrs] => Array ( [date] => 2012 )
```

... so some results (persuambly with a match on the title) have a higher wieght, and promoted above the description matches.

The fact that some tests have the date atttribute, and some dont, is just because you run the tests at different times? (so not a real problem, just an artifact of your testing?)

---

What I wonder, if you realise, you are just doing:

```
$sql_request = "SELECT * from post WHERE id IN {$rIds} LIMIT $search_start,{$config['search_number']}";
```

which will just return the results in arbitary order (what ever mysql deems fit).

Maybe you are looking at the results of the mysql query directly, and **not** realising you need to sort the results yourself, so they match the order returned from sphinx.

---

And you have odd LIMIT. The SQL query shouldnt have a limit, because paging is done in `sphinx` NOT in `mysql`.

Suggest

```
$sql_request = "SELECT * from post WHERE id IN {$rIds} ORDER BY FIELD(id,{$rIds})";
```

So that mysql will return you the results sorted correctly. 
From: http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD(id,{$rIds}) that doesn't work... `The Error returned was: 
Operand should contain 1 column(s) 

Error Number: 
1241 
`

Comment: Ah, your rIds, must already contain the () around the ids, for the field fynction, you dont want them in breackets. So have rIds just a plain list of ids (no brackets), then can do `WHERE id IN ($ids) ORDER BY FIELD(id,$ids)`